# Modifying lists using another list

Tags: python

I'm trying to modify my lists using another list which has the channel and the position in that channel I want to change(I want to change 128 to 0).

```
redchannel = [128, 128, 128, 128, 128]

greenchannel = [128, 128, 128, 128, 128]

bluechannel = [128, 128, 128, 128, 128]

index = [['b', 0], ['g', 1], ['r', 2], ['r', 4]]
```

I want to do this:

```
redchannel = [128, 128, 0, 128, 0]

greenchannel = [128, 0, 128, 128, 128]

bluechannel = [0, 128, 128, 128, 128]
```

I'm trying to iterate `index` and apply the changes that each item is showing

Comment: You have told us what you want to do. What exactly is your question to us? What work have you done on this problem so far, and just where are you stuck? Please show us some attempted code on your part.

Comment: @RoryDaulton I'm trying to iterate index and apply the changes that each item is showing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
channels = {
    'r': redchannel,
    'g': greenchannel,
    'b': bluechannel,
}
for channel, i in index:
    channels[channel][i] = 0
```